# jQuery sliding menu difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, jquery-animate, hidden

I'm trying to create a multi-layered menu that has cool sliding / fading-in effects. Right now, it works on my first click, but after that it fails.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>
    Development
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub 1</li>
            <li>Sub 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    Story
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub 1</li>
            <li>Sub 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    News
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub 1</li>
            <li>Sub 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var observeClicks = function(){
    var lis = $('#menu').children('li');

    lis.click(function(){
        lis.unbind();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $div = $($this.children('div')[0]);
        var $ul = $($div.children('ul')[0]);

        var clone = $ul.clone(true, true)
            .css({visibility: 'hidden', display: 'block'});
        clone.attr('style', clone.attr('style').replace('block', 'block !important'))
            .insertAfter($ul);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $ul.css({height: clone.css('height')});
            $div.css({height: clone.css('height')});
            clone.remove();
        }, 0);

        if(!lis.hasClass('current')){
            $this.addClass('current');
            $div.slideDown(350, function(){
                $ul.fadeIn(350);
                observeClicks();
            });
        }else{
            if(!$this.hasClass('current')){
                $current = $($('.current')[0]);
                $cdiv = $($current.children('div')[0]);
                $cul = $($cdiv.children('ul')[0]);

                $cdiv.css({height: $cul.css('height')});

                $this.addClass('current');
                $current.removeClass('current');
                $cul.fadeOut(350, function(){
                    $cdiv.slideUp(350, function(){
                        $div.slideDown(350, function(){
                            $ul.fadeIn(350);
                            observeClicks();
                        });
                    });
                });
            }else{
                observeClicks();
            }
        }
    });
}
observeClicks();
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
}

#menu div {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

The first interesting problem that I ran into was, instead of sliding, my menu would just "pop" in. That was because the div didn't take up space until the elements within it were showing. So I overcame that by giving it a fixed area. (Width is set in CSS, and Height is set in JavaScript). I think this is where the problem may lie, I insert a dummy element, read it's height, assign that to the div, and then remove the element. It's sketchy I know but I couldn't find a better way.

Anyways, when I first click on a menu item, it works perfectly. But as soon as I try my second click, it seems that the height does not get set for the div, and there is no sliding effect. [**Check it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/yL944/11/)

You may also notice, that instead of me trying to mess around with `.stop()` for the animations, I just unbind the click handler and then re-bind them after all of the animations have finished. That was deliberate, and I had this problem before adding that in. If someone could show me what to fix that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I made this a while ago. Might be useful if you want less code for a similar menu: http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that the problem is in the clone-height piece of code. I'm not sure about why it is only working with the first element clicked, but you could fix it by simply setting this elements heights in css:

```
#menu div {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

And removing the js code that clone and asign heights, It looks ok in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7EHu/

Comment: I suppose I could do it this way, but I was hoping of finding an automatic way of getting the height so when I add/remove things from my menu, I don't have to worry about tweaking the CSS over and over.

Comment: You could just assign a height to the components with a simple lineheight-depending operation: $div.css({height: $ul.children().lenght*$ul.css('lineHeight')}); You don't need the clonation and timer, that are far more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this instead of your code:

```
#menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
}

#menu div {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li ul {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

JS

```
 $("#menu > li").click(function(){
      $('#menu .active').slideUp(350).removeClass('active');
      $(this).find('div').slideDown(350,function() {
          $(this).addClass('active');
      });
 });
```

Here si a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yL944/12/

Comment: I'm trying to get the effect of sliding down, and then fading in, not just sliding down.